# Why is Java command working with java files as parameter

Tags: java, java-11, javacompiler

I have java file `HelloWorld.java` with the following code:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
    }
}
```

Now my understanding is, to compile and run this we need two steps: Step 1)`javac HelloWorld.java` Step 2)`java HelloWorld`. So clearly the command java takes the class file name as its input parameter.

However if I do `java HelloWorld.java`, it prints the output of the program despite the fact that I have passed the java filename and not the class name to it. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Can someone clarify this please?

Java - `openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS(AWS Corretto)`

OS - `Amazon Linux 2(red hat based OS)`

Infra - `AWS EC2 instance`

Edit: Also I noticed this happens only if the corresponding classfile is not there in the directory. If the corresponding classfile is there, it takes gives the error: `error: class found on application class path: HelloWorld`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was introduced in java 11.

If you have installed a JDK, you can call `javac` directly using the source file.

```
java <Class>.java
```

is basically the same as

```
javac <Class>.java
java <Class>
```

Comment: It was Java 11; see https://www.journaldev.com/24601/java-11-features for example.

Comment: Yes, I just added it ;)

Answer (score 2):

This was a new feature introduced in Java 11 to enhance the java launcher to run a program supplied as a single file of Java source code. **For more info you can visit the link [JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330)**